# Function add(num1, num2) not working?

Tags: javascript

I have a simple addition calculator Javascript code. It works entirely fine, but when I try using the `add(num1, num2)` function on two variables, rather than adding the two it simply prints them next to each other.

For example, I type in 5 and 4
It would print `54` in 'Answer'

If I remove the part that gets the value from the inputs and replace them it with numbers, I can call `add(num1, num2)` and it works fine. For example, I can say `add(5, 3)` and the return would be `8`, just not working with variables.

Here is the code

```
var back = 0;

function add(num1, num2) {
    return num1 + num2;
} 

function functions() {
    if (back==0) 
    {
        var first = document.getElementById("number1").value;
        var second = document.getElementById("number2").value;
        var Addition = add(first, second);
        document.getElementById("number1").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("number2").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("Answer").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("Answer").value = "Answer: " + Addition;
        document.getElementById("write").value = "Go Back";
        back = back+1;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("Answer").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("number1").style.display = 'inline';
        document.getElementById("number2").style.display = 'inline';
        document.getElementById("write").value = "Add";
        back = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're concatenating strings. Make numbers out of them first.

Comment: To convert from type `String` to `Number` (base 10) you can just add a plus sign before the string variable. Example: `var n = "10"; add(+n, +n)`

Answer (score 5):

When you get the value of the user input, it is return as a string. So when you type 5 and 4, it returns as '5' and '4'. So you use parseInt to then change it to a number.

```
var first = document.getElementById("number1").value;
var second = document.getElementById("number2").value;

first = parseInt(first, 10);
second = parseInt(second, 10);
```

The `, 10` is just letting the computer know you are working with base 10 values (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) and not like base2 values (0,1,1,1,1,0,0) or something else.

Comment: Or use unary `+` like `+first + +second`.

Answer (score 0):

```
return parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert values to numbers, you can use [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) function to do so

```
function add(num1, num2) {
    return Number(num1) + Number(num2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices to solve this problem :

1- Use Typescript then compile it to Javascript

2- Use Javascript and define types of inputs :

```
var button = document.querySelector("button");
var input1 = document.getElementById("num1");
var input2 = document.getElementById("num2");
function add(num1, num2) {
    if (typeof num1 === 'number' && typeof num2 === 'number') {
        return num1 + num2;
    }
    else {
        return +num1 + +num2;
    }
}

button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    console.log(add(+input1.value, +input2.value));
});
```